# Wavelets, How can a zero padding length n signal be truncated to n coefficients from which a signal can be reconstructed in R

Tags: r

Wavelet transform is defined for infinite length signals. Finite length signals must be extended in some way before they can be transformed. I know that periodic replication and zero padding are appropriate for signals that begin and end on the baseline, while mirror-image replication and linear extrapolation provide continutity at the boundaries for signals that do not begin or end on the baseline. Periodic replication either wraps arround or reflects signal detail in the region beyond the boundaries and this distorts the interpretation of the transform coefficients near the boundaries.

I have a time series of limited duration not extending beyond the signal range and that is not a power of two as required by the transform (using package wavethresh, function "wst" Packet-ordered non-decimated wavelet transform). Zero padding seems to be the only way forward for signals that begin and end on the baseline also zero padding makes no assumptions of the signal after the boundaries describing only the signal, however zero padding results in non length preserving transform (one in which the transform vector is longer than the signal vector) and large perturbations in the transform space are not reflected in the signal space.

By doing zero padding (added at the end and beginning of the series) my question is how can I truncate the zero padding length signal of n coefficients to obtain n coefficients as be able to reconstruct exacly the signal in R. Have reviewed the different packages in R and have not found a way around this.

Comment: Please provide reproducible examples.

Comment: Two possibilities: try zero-padding to `2^n` and see what you get; and consider a spline fit to your dataset, then using the resultant spline function to generate `2^n` samples equally spaced across the existing time range (rather than at the original time spacings)

Comment: Thanks Carl for the hints